# IndexedDB/React: Can't create a new store or perform any crud after DB creation

Tags: reactjs, typescript, indexeddb

I'm building a React test app to understand better how the IndexedDB API works.

However, I'm struggling updating the data (creating store).

The db will only be updated if I refresh the page and the DB has been already created. Otherwise the `onsuccess` and the `onupgradeneeded` are not invoked at all.

**iddb.ts**

```
let request: IDBOpenDBRequest;
let db: IDBDatabase;
let version = 1;

// we will use this function to create a new store in our indexedDB
    export const initDB = () => {
  console.log('initDB');
  request = window.indexedDB.open(DBName.Main); // keep the existing version if it exists
  /* 
  onupgradeneeded is called when the database is created or the version is changed
  the version should only change when we add, remove or modify a store
  */
  request.onupgradeneeded = (_event) => {
    db = request.result;
    if (!db.objectStoreNames.contains(StoreName.Users)) {
      console.log(`Creating ${StoreName.Users} store`);
      db.createObjectStore(StoreName.Users, { keyPath: 'id' });
    }
    if (!db.objectStoreNames.contains(StoreName.Posts)) {
      console.log(`Creating ${StoreName.Posts} store`);
      db.createObjectStore(StoreName.Posts, { keyPath: 'id' });
    }
  };

  // discard the old connection
  request.onsuccess = (_event) => {
    // this is not needed apparently (check it)
    console.log('request.onsuccess - initDB');
    version = request.result.version;
  };

};

export const deleteDB = () => {
  request = window.indexedDB.deleteDatabase(DBName.Main);
  request.onsuccess = (_event) => {
    console.log('Database deleted successfully');
  };
};

export const createStore = (storeName: StoreName) => {
  version += 1;
  request = window.indexedDB.open(DBName.Main, version); // open a new connection to the database

  request.onupgradeneeded = (_event) => {
    db = request.result;
    if (!db.objectStoreNames.contains(storeName)) {
      console.log(`Creating ${storeName} store`);
      db.createObjectStore(storeName, { keyPath: 'id' });
    }
  };

  request.onsuccess = (_event) => {
    console.log(`Store ${storeName} created successfully`);
    // close the database connection
  };

  request.onerror = (event) => {
    console.error('Error creating store', event);
  };
};

// we will use this function to add data to our indexedDB
export const addData = <T>(storeName: StoreName, data: T) => {
  // close prev connection
  // open a new connection to the database
  request = window.indexedDB.open(DBName.Main, version);

  // this works
  request.onsuccess = (_event) => {
    console.log('request.onsuccess');
    db = request.result;
    const tx = db.transaction(storeName, 'readwrite');
    const store = tx.objectStore(storeName);
    store.add(data);
  };
};
```

types definitions

```
export enum DBName {
  Main = 'main',
}

export enum StoreName {
  Users = 'users',
  Posts = 'posts',
  News = 'news',
}
```

These methods are later invoked in the client

```
// someComponent.tsx
import { StoreName, addData, initDB, createStore, deleteDB } from "../lib/iddb";

<button onClick={() => initDB()}>Init DB</button>
<button onClick={() => deleteDB()}>Delete DB</button>
<button onClick={() => createStore(StoreName.News)}>Create News DB</button>
```

As per my understading:

- To add a store -> increase the `version` and `open` a new DB, then update `onupgradeneeded`.
- To perform CRUDs -> `open` the DB and perfrom a transaction `onsuccess`.

What I can see, given an existing DB and whenever there's a previous `open` connection, the `IDBDatabase` listeners won't be invoked. That's why I must restart the app to make them work.

Here's a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/priceless-rumple-utmfbz?file=%2Fpages%2Findex.tsx&selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A1%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A5%2C%22startColumn%22%3A1%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A4%7D%5D) with repro

**EDIT**
I made the `addData` work by simply not passing any version. However, trying to open a new connection increasing the version breaks the CRUD operations and no store is created unles I refresh (as mentioned earlier).